# Add class to <body> if query string is in url

Tags: jquery, query-string, addclass

I'm working with woocommerce. When you use the product filters it renders a url with a query string (or what I think is a query string)
http://www.webdesignui.com/looms/browse/?filtering=1&filter_collection=1481

For some reason WooCommerce doesn't change the body class based on the url you are on. It keeps the "archive" as the body class.

I'd like to figure out a way to say, if the url has ?filtering=, add class="filterison". Something like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(url.indexOf('a[href*="/looms/browse/?filtering=1') > -1){
        $("body").addClass("filterison");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.indexOf('filtering=')`? You don't want the `a[href*="` part, and you don't really need the rest of the url before the ? either.

Answer (score 2):

You are confused between Jquery selector type of syntax with normal string `indexOf` method.

If you want to find if a string has a substring then you must use `indexOf` which outputs the index of the starting character of the substring within the main string.

EG : `"I am a main string".indexOf('string')` will give the index of `s` as output

So in your case it must be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(url.indexOf('/looms/browse/?filtering=1') > -1){
        $("body").addClass("filterison");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Reddy, thanks for the response. I added the code you provided and it's still not adding <body class="filterison"
http://www.webdesignui.com/looms/browse/?filtering=1&filter_collection=1103

What is > -1 actually doing, sorry newbie over here trying to make sense of it all

Comment: It's just a way to check for a substring.. So when checking for a substring in a bigger string the substring can occur right at the start. At this scenario. IndexOf will return 0.. So the logic is like 0 > -1 ...

Comment: Gotcha. Based on the code you provided, I'm still not getting the body class added if the ?filtering is available. Any ideas?

Comment: @Tom we are checking for `'/looms/browse/?filtering=1'` this substring in the code and not just `'?filtering'`.. if you only want to check that then use this `url.indexOf('filtering') > -1`

Comment: Hey Reddy, I wasn't able to get this to work I had to use if(window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1)
Eitherway it's working! Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @Tom glad to help. But what was there in 'url' ? I thought you already had the required URL data in it... Also by just checking `?` might not be best approach.. As any utl with query string will have `?` in it..

Comment: Good point. I should probably change it out to filtering
http://www.webdesignui.com/looms/browse/?filtering=1&filter_collection=1481

I was basically looking for any url that has ?filtering, add a class to the body

Answer (score 1):

This was the final code I was able to get working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) {
       $("body").addClass("filterison");
    }
});
</script>
```